# Passing a parameter in a URL from HTML

Tags: html, http

First off, let me beg forgiveness for being such a noob at web development. I have looked everywhere for how to do this and can't find anything that tells me specifically.

Here is my link:

```
<td><a style="color:red;text-align:left" href=/sponsor/manageuser.htm?user=" 
+ target=_self"</a></td>
```

I need the parameter "user" to be appended and I also need the exact same value as user as the link. Like this:

```
<td><a style="color:red;text-align:left" 
href=/sponsor/manageuser.htm?user="12345" 12345</a></td>
```

The problem is that I have to put the param and the link inside the  tag. At least I think that's the problem So you click on 12345 link, it appends 12345 to the URL and passes it as a GET method. My form is a GET:

```
<form class="frm" method="get" name="currentusers" id="currentusers" 
action="currentusers.htm">
```

And then here's what my URL looks like and of course I get a 404 error:

```
http://localhost:8080/sponsor/manageuser.htm?user=target=
```

Any advice is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Your `href` has invalid quotes: `href=/sponsor/manageuser.htm?user=" 
+ target="_self"`. And what you're asking cannot be done with raw HTML; you would need JavaScript or a server-side language.

Comment: @Obsidian Age: I see the error. This is in a JSP. Can I use Java code to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? Corrected the error in the 'href' as you said.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery way:

What you can do is have each link call a function and pass the value of the link into the function.  The function append() will then add a hidden input value with the number you clicked on.  Finally, the function will submit the form to the manageuser.htm page with the "?user=1234" as you requested.

You can see how the code works by copying and pasting this code and opening it on your computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <form id = "form1" method="get" action="sponsor/manageuser.htm"> 

        <table>

            <tr>

                <td><button id="1543" onclick="append(1543)">1543</button></td>

                <td><button id="3515" onclick="append(3515)">3515</button></td>

                <td><button id="1115" onclick="append(1115)">1115</button></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>

<script>

    function append(user_number)
    {   

        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "user").attr('value', user_number).appendTo('#form1');

        $('#form1').submit();

     }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work. It didn't append the user name from the button to the end of the URL.

Comment: Nope, I think it's my fault. Sorry. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: No. I was wrong. It doesn't work. I may have configured it incorrectly, but it is not appending the number onto the end of the url. Can you elaborate?